# Max YCQL connections in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

What is the parameter that controls the maximum number of connections per tserver for ycql? I am looking at the equivalent of `--ysql_max_connections` which is having a default of 300. Is it applicable for YCQL also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to limit connections on YCQL on the server-side.
But YCQL connections are multi-plexed, therefore you don't need many.
Are you sure you have 300 ycql connections on the server?
If yes, how many client-apps processes & servers are you starting and in what language? You may need at most 2-4 connections for each client-process. Some docs on configuring connections on the client side: https://support.yugabyte.com/hc/en-us/articles/4417928616845-How-to-configure-max-connections-in-YCQL-and-YSQL.